# Problem installing "nloptr" in R 4.2.2 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, nlopt

My installation of "ggpubr" on Rstudio (based on R 4.2.2) in Ubuntu 22.04 failed because of issues in installing "nloptr". I installed NLOPT based on guides in https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Installation/, but nloptr installation is still failing but with another kind of error.

Here are the last lines:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -o nloptr.so init_nloptr.o nloptr.o test-C-API.o test-runner.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/local/lib -lnlopt -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: nloptr.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘nloptr’
```

Any help is appreciated.

Best,
Amir

Comment: Open Terminal CTRL + ALT + T, then `sudo apt install libblas-dev liblapack-dev gfortran`.

Comment: Yes, and even easier:  `sudo apt install r-base-dev` -- a package we added _explicitly_ to so that you would have common requirements for building from source.  It depends on these build tools you are missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments by @jay.sf and myself give you the narrowest answer: you attempt to build from source, and compiling *and linking* requires the so-called `-dev` packages.  So install `r-base-dev`.

Looking beyond this for a second though, you are on Ubuntu 22.04 and you have `r-cran-nloptr` inside the distribution too (albeit an older version). So `sudo apt install r-cran-nloptr` works as well.

And since this summer there is [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) which gives you (on Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04) *every CRAN package as an Ubuntu binary* and is generally current.  It is easy to set up and the command `install.packages("ggpubr")` would then *reliably and quickly* install the package and all its dependencies from binaries.

Comment: Thanks! Installing `r-base-dev` solved all the problems.